# npm can not install package even though it is in the repository

Tags: npm, npm-install, nexus, nexus3

I have the problem that I can not install a package even though it is in our  private Nexus npm repository.

```
# npm install @company-scope/packagename@3.4.1                                                                                                                                        
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @company-scope/packagename@3.4.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

`npm show` shows that the package is there.

```
# npm show @company-scope/packagename                                                                                                                                                

@company-scope/packagename@3.4.1 | Proprietary | deps: 1 | versions: 14
Packagename is a support library.

dist
.tarball: http://nexus.company.lan:8080/repository/npm-public/@company-scope/packagename/-/packagename-3.4.1.tgz
.shasum: bcbd4fceab2540lk92bb8284d9cae3cd7897af48
.integrity: sha512-Tm2easZ6movvxTUJtPeWuU3yVv6nZggrfGQ1835dxoHLIkVpYnoxf51syIo9NbaIVBob7nvuBvak3LCtP7DUWg==

dependencies:
onnxruntime-web: 1.11.0 

dist-tags:
latest: 3.4.1  

published 18 hours ago
```

I already tried:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

What could be problem? What can I do to install the package?

Comment: does `npm install @company-scope/packagename@latest` work in this case?